# Get MID from CloudpagesURL()

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, sfmc-business-unit, wsproxy

I am trying to create an unsubscribe page at the parent BU level for multiple child BUs. I want to use impersonatation with WSProxy in order to log the unsubscribe at the right BU, to do that I need the MID from where the email was sent. However, I noticed that when I use CloudpagesURL() in the email from the child BU and then on the parent BU Cloudpage grabbing the MID with Attribute.GetValue("memberid"), it gives me the mid of the parent BU, not of the BU that sent the email. Is it possible to grab the MID from the CloudpagesURL encrypted parameters? Or will it always just use the context of where the Cloudpage is executing, in my case the parentBU?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass a custom attribute in the cloudpagesurl() function and leverage that

`%%=CloudPagesURL(ID, 'MID', memberid)=%%`

Then on your cloudpage:

`SET@VAR= QUERYPARAMETER('MID')`

Comment: That makes sense. I was hoping for a "cleaner" solution where the people that are going to work in the account won't have to think about this but I guess it's a minor thing to add the MID as parameter.

Comment: @ArthurNoort Why did you need the MID? the logunsubevent is based off jobid, jobid ties back to MID. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/unsubscribing_and_logging_an_unsubevent_with_a_logunsubevent_execute_call.html

Comment: Didn't realise that! I was using the MID to impersonate the right BU with WSProxy.